# Error "unable to resolve docker endpoint: open /root/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory" when deploying to elastic beanstalk through bitbucket

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to upload to elastic beanstalk with bitbucket and I am using the following yml file:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: "Install Server"
          image: node:10.19.0
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
      - step:
          name: "Install and Build Client"
          image: node:14.17.3
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - cd ./client && npm install
            - npm run build
      - step:
          name: "Build zip"
          script:
            - cd ./client
            - shopt -s extglob
            - rm -rf !(build)
            - ls
            - cd ..
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
            - zip -r application.zip . -x "node_modules/**"
      - step:
          name: "Deployment to Development"
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - ls
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: "application.zip"
```

All goes well until I reach the AWS deployment and I get this error:

```
+ docker container run \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:ro \
   --volume=/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker:ro \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy \
   --workdir=$(pwd) \
   --label=org.bitbucket.pipelines.system=true \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME="$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE="$BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE="$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT_UUID="$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY_FILE="$BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY_FILE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BRANCH="$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT="$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG="$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG" \
   --env=CI="$CI" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_COMMIT="$BITBUCKET_COMMIT" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR" \
   --env=PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN="$PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL="$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   --env=DOCKER_HOST="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_SHARED_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy" \
   --env=APPLICATION_NAME="$APPLICATION_NAME" \
   --env=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \
   --env=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="$AWS_REGION" \
   --env=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
   --env=ENVIRONMENT_NAME="$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" \
   --env=ZIP_FILE="application.zip" \
   --add-host="host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   bitbucketpipelines/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2
unable to resolve docker endpoint: open /root/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

I'm unsure how to approach this as I've followed the documentation bitbucket lies out exactly and it doesn't look like there's any place to add a .pem file.